# How to create a table from a distinct in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model with an element `vchClient` and `vchStatus`. I need to generate a table with every distinct client in the records and the count for each status of that client. What I have tried is:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ReportesClient(String fromDay = null, String toDay = null)
{
    if (fromDay != string.Empty && toDay != String.Empty)
    {
        return View(entidad.tblKaizens.Select(r => r.vchClient).Distinct());
    }
    else if (fromDay == null || toDay == null || fromDay == String.Empty || toDay == String.Empty)
    {
        return View(entidad.tblKaizens.Where((r => r.vchStatus.Equals("Something"))).ToList());
    }
}
```

View:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Celula
    </th>
    <th>
        Total
    </th>
    <th>
        Implementado
    </th>
    <th>
        No viable
    </th>
    <th>
        Transferido
    </th>
    <th>
        En revision
    </th>
    <th>
        Sin revisar
    </th>
    <th>
        Duracion Promedio 
    </th>

</tr>
<tr>

</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.vchClient)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Model.Count()
        </td>
        <td>
            @Model.Where(r => r.vchStatus.Equals("Implementado")).Count()
        </td>
        <td>
            @Model.Where(r => r.vchStatus.Equals("No viable")).Count()
        </td>
        <td>         
            @Model.Where(r => r.vchStatus.Equals("Transferido")).Count()
        </td>

        <td>
            @Model.Where(r => r.vchStatus.Equals("En revision")).Count()
        </td>
        <td>
            @Model.Where(r => r.vchStatus.Equals("Sugerido")).Count()
        </td>
        <td>
            @Model.Average(r => r.intDuration)
       </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I thought this could work but it is not, I got all the records not by client and the same with count and average is from all the records in the model between the dates selected by the user.

Comment: Do you have any error with what you tried? Can you share the classes?

Comment: Is this information in the database?  If so, are you using EF or some other framework?

Comment: Hi, i have alrdy solved the issue, all i had to do was to define item as Model.vchClienct.Distinct.